# SAP : Transfer Multiple Users $TMP Objects to One Folder/Package

Tags: abap

Is there any way to Transfer all the $TMP objects of Multiple Users to One Folder/Package ?.

It would be great to hear the solution.

I tried but you can transfer to only one package in SE03.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only one or few users, it may be more easy to do it via `SE80` (see second answer below), otherwise you use `SE03`.

## SE03 (or SM30 TADIR)

`SE03` > Transport Organizer Tools > Object Directory > Change Object Directory Entries

(this is the same as starting `SM30` > `TADIR`)

[image: SM30 TADIR selection]

Select the parent node via the button "Select/Deselect" (sub-tree) or function key <kbd>F6</kbd>:

[image: SM30 TADIR Select subtree]

[image: SM30 TADIR MASS Command field]

[image: SM30 TADIR MASS change of object directory entry]

## SE80

If there are few users, you may do it user by user: select the "Local objects" and indicate one user.

Select the objects by selecting the first one with the mouse, and the last one by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> and selecting it with the mouse, that will select all the objects between the first and last selected. You may also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd> to add or remove one by one.

Then use the option to assign them to the new package:

[image: SE80 Change Package Assignment]

Comment: If you have list of users that you want to move, in option 1 you can restrcit the list by using 'Person Responsible' selection

Comment: Impressive @Sandra Rossi. Thank you so much.